# difference between 'let' and 'var' inside a function which has a switch case

Tags: javascript

i was working on a functionality, i have found an issue while using let inside the switch case of a function. if i change to var it works.  I have read difference between the let and var. But is this case is causing issue of block level scope. Little bit confused.

Any help appreciated

```js
var a = "sample data"
const returnDataOfLet = (a) => {
switch(typeof a){
    case "string": 
      let a = a.split(" ") // will throw an error change let to var it will work
      return a 
}
}

console.log(returnDataOfLet(a))
```

Comment: Remove the `let` entirely, or, even better, use a *new* variable name

Answer (score 2):

Inside the block you declare `let a`. This creates a new variable `a`.

Then you call `a.split`. This throws an error because `a` is `undefined` (it has to be `undefined`: you haven't give it a value yet).

The program stops at the point because of the exception.

---

If you use `var` instead of `let`, then the `var` is ignored completely because there is already an `a` declared in that scope.

Since you haven't created a new variable, `a` is the argument you passed to the function.

This is a string, so you can call `split` on it and assign the result back to the `a` variable declared in the argument list.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://blog.pragmatists.com/let-your-javascript-variables-be-constant-1633e56a948d) is a elaborate guide on this topic. Generally:

- let is block scoped, while var is function scoped (not visible from outside the function).
- let cannot be accessed before declaration (var can be, and is actually the source of many bugs and confusion in the JS world)
- **let cannot be redeclared**

The way you use let here, the variable is redeclared at any iteration, that causes the error. You can always reassign the value of a though.

```js
let a = "sample data";
const returnDataOfLet = (a) => {
  switch (typeof a) {
    case "string":
      return a.split(" ");
  }
}

console.log(returnDataOfLet(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

The globally defined `var a` is not the same a which is passed to the function as `parameter`. Its just like an `alias` for a `variable`.
and also in `case "`string`"` no need to again create `a` as it is already there in the function. Here it is not a problem with `scopes` but `definition` and `parameters`.

```js
var a = "sample data"
const returnDataOfLet = (a) => {
switch(typeof a){
    case "string": 
      a = a.split(" ") // will throw an error change let to var it will work
      return a 
}
}

console.log(returnDataOfLet(a))
```

If you want to use `let` use another variable name

```js
var a = "sample data"
const returnDataOfLet = (a) => {
switch(typeof a){
    case "string": 
      let b = a.split(" ") // will throw an error change let to var it will work
      return b 
}
}

console.log(returnDataOfLet(a))
```